# Line chart with separate lines for different groupings in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have data in the following format:

[image]

I want to produce a line chart with three lines for each value in Field1 (I.e. a line for A, B and C)

How is this achieved? Do I need to split my data into three separate tables?

Thanks

Comment: In Power Query Pivot A, B, and C to columns. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/pivot-columns

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to split your data into 3 tables which is not needed.

Please check the Power BI screenshots to achieve it simply.

[image: FGD]

[image: FGDdd]